# Prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $\sigma$ such that $x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{\sigma(n)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\left(x_n\right)_{n=0}^\infty\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ converges and is finite and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|x_n\right|$ diverges and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary real number. Prove that there exists a bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{\sigma(n)}$.

My idea:

Let $p_i$ be the index of the $i$-th non-negative number in the sequence and let $m_i$ be the index of the $i$-th negative number in the sequence. Then $(p_i)$ and $(m_i)$ must be infinite sequences and we construct sigma as follows:

If $x≥0$ then $\sigma(0)=p_1$, else $\sigma(0)=m_1$. Then, if $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{\sigma(k)}≤x$ we define $\sigma(n)=p_i$ such that all the $p_1,...,p_{i-1}$ are already attained by $\sigma$ and else we put $\sigma(n)=m_j$ such that such that all the $m_1,...,m_{j-1}$ are already attained by $\sigma$.

I have proven that $\sigma$ is indeed a bijection, but I fail to prove rigorously that this is the right bijection. Am I on the right track? If so, how to conclude?

Comment: Riemann says: I beat you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works.

To prove it, let $s_q$ be the $q$th partial sum of the rearranged series, and let $q_0$ be the first turning point (where $\sigma(q_0)$ and $\sigma(q_0 + 1)$ are of a different nature, one being a $p_i$ and the other an $n_i$). Then it can be seen by induction that for all $q \geq q_0$, we have $|s_q - x| \leq \sup_{i \geq q} |x_{\sigma(i)}|$. The term on the right tends to zero as $q \to +\infty$ because $x_j \to 0$. (Any rearrangement of a sequence converging to zero also converges to zero.)